# How to adjust the View according to phone size programmatically?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, swift2

I have created a view programmatically using frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 330) but when i tried to change my device the content size remains the same and bcoz of which it didn't look proper. I want to adjust the UI according to phone size. How can I do that.

```
    import UIKit

extension UIImageView {
    public func imageFromUrl(urlString: String) {
        if let url = NSURL(string: urlString) {
            let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
            NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {
                (response: NSURLResponse?, data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if let imageData = data as NSData? {
                    self.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class NewsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var NewsArray = [AnyObject] ()
    var NewsTableView: UITableView

    var NewsTableViewController: ViewController?

    let customView:UIView = UIView()

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        NewsTableView = UITableView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 330), style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)
        NewsTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NewsTableView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        NewsTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100

        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        setupViews()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func tableView(newsTableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("News :\(NewsArray.count)")
        if (NewsArray.count > 1) {
            print("NewsData:\(NewsArray[0]["desc"]!!)")
        }
        return NewsArray.count
    }

    func tableView(NewsTableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let NewsCell = NewsTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("NewsTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NewsTableViewCellForSubCat
        NewsCell.nameLabel.text = NewsArray[indexPath.row]["title"] as! String
        NewsCell.descLabel.text = NewsArray[indexPath.row]["desc"] as! String
        NewsCell.imgUser.imageFromUrl("http://104.131.162.14:3033/theme/New/img1.png")

        print("NewsDataInside:\(NewsArray[indexPath.row]["title"] as! String)")

        NewsCell.NewsTableViewController = NewsTableViewController
        return NewsCell
    }

    func setupViews() {
        NewsTableView.dataSource = self
        NewsTableView.delegate = self

        NewsTableView.scrollEnabled = false
        //newsTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.brownColor()
        //newsTableView.separatorColor = UIColor.blueColor()

        NewsTableView.registerClass(NewsTableViewCellForSubCat.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "NewsTableViewCell")

        addSubview(NewsTableView)
    }

}
```

Comment: Try setting the frame in viewDidLoad()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
NewsTableView = UITableView(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds, style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)
```

or

```
NewsTableView = UITableView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height), style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)
```

(They accomplish the same thing, but the first one is more concise)

It takes the current phone size's frame and sets the frame to it.

Comment: Thanks @Benjamin both were working fine but I have used the 2nd one bcoz I want to use constant height.

Comment: @ChandanAnand No problem. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted so that future users can find the solution quickly :D

Comment: Well for landscape, if you want to adjust the width to be traditional "height" of the phone, then you would just have to change it to (0,0,UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height,330)

Comment: Actually I want to use both portrait and Landscape both according to users screen orientation.

Comment: Well then you will want to override the `didRotate` method for your app and then change the view size programmatically based on what orientation it changed to in order to have the proper sizing. I suggest looking up this method for further clarification.

Comment: One more thing can you help me in fetching the image from NewsArray NewsArray[indexPath.row]["image_url"]   As I am able to print only one image.

Comment: Well you only initialize NewsArray as a one-dimensional array, so you won't be able to have two parameters called.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with swift much. So may be help to solve your problem

Just take a `constant.h` file or you have already, define

`#define SCREEN_SIZE (UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds().size)`

use `SCREEN_SIZE.height` or `SCREEN_SIZE.width` where ever you want through out your project.

Happy coding ..